# Save values of a html table in python depending on the button pressed

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am trying to save the values of a html table's row to python variables. The problem is that I don't know the row of the table that the user of the website is going to choose (selection of row is done by clicking on a button in the same row). I want as soon as the user clicks a button, the other values in the row to be stored to a variable. How can this be done ?

For every row in the table I use this code:

```
<tr>
  <td>%s</td>
  <td>%s</td>
  <td>%s</td>
  <td><button id="myBtn%d">Edit Me !</button></td>
</tr> %(line['title'], line['prod_year'], line['company'], i)`
```

And for every button I use this script:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("myBtn%d").onclick = function () {
   location.href = "update_info";
  }     
</script>''' %(k)
```

Comment: You should post some example code, for example what one of your table rows looks like and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's 3 steps: extract the data from HTML, send data to server, and receive data on server and write it to storage. First, there is your table. Let's assume a row looks like this

```
<tr>
  <td>some</td>
  <td>data</td>
  <td>here</td>
  <td><button>save</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then there is Javascript that captures the `click` event of all the "save" buttons on the different rows

```
// Find all the buttons
var all_btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

// Attach event handlers
for (btn in all_btns) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', handleMyClick);
}

// Handle a click event
function handleMyClick(event) {
    // Find the table row where the click happened
    var tr = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    // Find all the data in the row
    var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var data = [];
    for (td in tds) {
        data.push(td.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Now you have all the `<td>` content in the `data` array, ready to send it to the server. That could be done via "AJAX" or via "form-data" `POST` or `GET`.

Then, on the server, your Python script needs to receive that incoming data and write it so some persistent storage. Are you using Django or Flask? A database or simple text files?

Comment: I use bottle and connect the site to a MySQL database

Comment: and how would the post method work to get the data array ?